# Include IP, Port in Python distribution

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I am using Python27 and distutils for bundling a script for clients that includes the server's IP and Port. I have to avoid hard-coding the server's IP, port values in the script itself and instead put them somewhere else in the package. Preferably, in a place where the client cannot modify. I am thinking of setup.py but don't know how to do it. The setup.py currently looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='cpu123',
    packages=['cpu12'],
    description='App to pull CPU Stats',

    install_requires=[
        "psutil",
        "socket",
        "time",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Or you can use one of Internet's greatest inventions, the DNS.

Comment: What do you mean "includes the server's IP and port?"

Comment: Sorry - did not understand the DNS part. By include 'ip, port', I mean, include the server's specific ip address and port number - hard coded in the original script - which I have to avoid and include these details somewhere else in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

These sound like conflicting requirements: the server address should not be editable, but you don’t want to hard-code it?  Why not hard-code it, if it never changes?

Minor point: the socket and time modules are included in the standard libraries, they are not third-party distributions that need to be in install_requires like psutil.